# Menu buttons not working

Tags: button, user-interface, actionscript, menu, actionscript-2

I am trying to make a menu screen that allows users to press on buttons that contain their following instances. I know I almost have it but I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

```
stop();

home_btn.onRelease {
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
graphics_btn.onRelease {
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
animation_btn.onRelease {
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried "_parent.gotoAnd..." in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  mx.utils.Delegate class :

import mx.utils.Delegate;

```
home_btn.onRelease = Delegate.create(this, function() {
    gotoAndStop(1);
})
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002284.html

Answer (score 0):

```
stop();

home_btn.onRelease = function() {
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
graphics_btn.onRelease = function() {
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
animation_btn.onRelease = function() {
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Add `=function()`